# Dump keystore content: Permission denied keytool java_cacerts

Tags: java, bash, ssl, dump, keytool

I am trying to get a dump of my Java keystore content, I am trying with the following query in terminal:

`keytool -list -v -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts > java_cacerts.txt`

it throws the following error:
`-bash: java_cacerts.txt: Permission denied`

I already tried changing permissions on several folders also on the cacerts file itself but without any results.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't have permission to write to your current working directory.
Firstly try creating the file `java_cacerts.txt` without any keytool command, you should get the same error running something like `touch java_cacerts.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have write permission on the folder where you try to export java_cacerts.txt .

Answer (score 0):

The given answers lead to the solution. I added a different (100% sure writable) location before the java_cacerts.txt and it was able to write now. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've run recently into a similar problem.

If you run the same command with Administrator rights, you'll be able to generate the file without problems.